# Is it possible to reconstruct a surface from its curvature function?

Tags: differential-geometry

If we know the Gaussian curvature and/or mean curvature of a surface embedded in R3, is it possible to reconstruct the original surface? If yes, how would one go about doing such a thing?

Comment: See also [Does the curvature determine the metric?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/162175/472818)

Comment: @zwim What do curves have to do with surfaces?

Comment: I just didn't pay attention the linked post was for curves, that'all.

Answer (score 0):

According to the following question posted previously and already answered is not possible: [Gaussian curvature and mean curvature sufficient to characterize a surface?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756051/gaussian-curvature-and-mean-curvature-sufficient-to-characterize-a-surface?rq=1).
According to the Bonnet theorem (https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Bonnet_theorem).

Comment: I think you misunderstood the linked answer: The surface is unique up to a rigid motion of ${\mathbb R}^3$.

Comment: If you know both curvatures, the surface is unique up to rigid motion. If you know only one, there is no uniqueness.

Comment: More precisely, once you prescribe the curvature and 2nd fundamental form, not the mean curvature, then the surface is determined.

Comment: There's also a whole issue of integrability. I cannot prescribe arbitrary first and second fundamental forms and expect to get even a piece of a surface; the Gauss and Mainardi-Codazzi equations are necessary and sufficient conditions to be able to integrate. I see now that the linked answer already tells you that.